# passing "non const reference to iterator" to a function

Tags: templates, c++11, vector, iterator

I have a struct

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    double x, y, z;
}MyStruct;
```

I have a function

```
template <class Iterator>
bool
SomeFunc    ( 
                Iterator&        anotherVecBegin
            )
{
...
}
```

And this is how I call the function.

```
std::vector<MyStruct> mySt;
SomeFunc(mySt.begin());
```

I get the error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type..`

which seem obvious to me, since arguments are going to be on the stack until the lifetime of a function.

The whole purpose will be killed if I make the reference constant, since I won't be able to insert values in a vector

I tried and failed:

```
template <class Iterator>
bool
SomeFunc    ( 
                const Iterator&        anotherVecBegin
            )
{
     MyStruct pt1;
     pt1.x = 10, pt1.y = 20, pt3.z = 30;
    *(anotherVecBegin)++ = pt1;
}
```

And this also makes sense to me.

But I am searching out for a way to:

1. insert an element using iterator, inside a function, when iterator is being passed a reference to some function

pl suggest

Comment: Take the iterator by value, not by reference. Most (possibly all) standard library functions do.

Comment: Parameter passing aside, note that you are **not**, in fact, inserting an element into the container - you are overwriting the first element (or more generally, the element the iterator is referring to). When there is no first element (or more generally, when the iterator is not dereferenceable) - as is the case in your example, when `mySt` vector is empty - your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `I am searching out for a way to insert an element using iterator` You can't. Nothing you do with an iterator alone can change the size of the container, only its contents. To insert (or erase) an element, one must needs call an appropriate method on the container itself.

Comment: @Igor, you were right, I had to take iterator by value and I instead used `back_inserter`.. pl comment if there is something wrong in what I did..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I did not need to have a reference to the iterator.

Instead I simply used `back_inserter`

From callee method, I do:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> mySt;
SomeFunc(std::back_inserter(mySt));
std::cout << "Struct size after insert: " << mySt.size() << std::endl;
```

and function then changes to:

```
template <class BackInsertIterator>
bool
SomeFunc    ( 
                const BackInsertIterator        anotherVecBegin
            )
{
     MyStruct pt1;
     pt1.x = 10, pt1.y = 20, pt3.z = 30;
    *(anotherVecBegin)++ = pt1;
    // ... remaining code
}
```